# Parsing csv file to filter rows based on a matching set of characters from a column value

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, csv, text-formatting

Consider the following csv file:

```
A,3300   
B,8440   
B,8443   
B,8444 
C,304
C,404  
M,5502   
M,5511
```

The actual csv file is big (around 60,000 rows). I have only included a small version to describe the problem.

I need to create a script to filter rows based on the second field to group in a single row those with a matching set of characters (replacing the second field with the matching set of characters).

In other words, I expect the following output from the given csv file above:

```
A,3300   
B,844  
C,304
C,404 
M,55
```

Please note that ONLY the content on the second csv field is relevant for the purpose of the script. So any matching/un-matching occurrence in the other fields need to remain on the file as they are.

Would awk be useful to accomplish this task? or any other built-in function?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to U/L! Is it only the *first* characters of the second field that you would look at? What about `C,404` and `C,304`? What would the result be? Please do not answer in comments, but edit your question to clarify. (You can then tag me in the comments so I am notified, by mentioning @Sparhawk ).

Comment: Thanks @Sparhawk , I will check your proposal later today and come back to you with some feedback. The question has been edited as you suggested.

Comment: The handling of `C,304` and `C,404` makes no sense. The longest prefix string is empty, so the output ought to be a single line saying `C,`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small `awk` function to find common starting characters between 2 strings:

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}
function common_chars(a,b, o){
    split(a,asplit,"")
    split(b,bsplit,"")
    n=1
    while (asplit[n]==bsplit[n]){
        o=o""asplit[n]
        n++
    }
    return o
}
s[$1] {v[$1]=common_chars(v[$1],$2)}
!s[$1] {v[$1]=$2;s[$1]=1 }
END {for(a in v){print a,v[a]}}
' file
```

If `$1` has not been seen (state is saved in `s[$1]`), save `$2` in array `v[$1]=$2`.
If it has been seen, set `v[$1]` with the return of the function between itself and `$2`. The function simply runs a while loop on the single characters until it finds the first characters not matching.

For `C,404` and `C,304` it will print `C,`

Output:

```
A,3300   
B,844
C,
M,55
```

Comment: Thanks @pLumo I will check the proposal and come back to you with some feedback.

Comment: Hey @pLumo , I just tested your suggestion and indeed it gives the result you posted above, but that is not the desired output, sorry I should have stated that clearly on my original post. If there are no matching occurrences on the second csv field then I need to preserve the entire row as it is (no matter what the other field is). I edited the original post to clarify. Also I'm trying to understand your code so that I can try to modify as needed, but I am not that good on Linux, so if you have some time to take a look and help it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be somewhat slow for 60,000 rows, but seems to work.
Do **not** put quotes around `$line` here!

I still have this odd feeling that there's a mistake somewhere in that script, that would show with more data to work on...

```bash
$ sort -u testfile | datamash -t, -g1 collapse 2  \
| tr ',' ' ' | while read line ; do ./my_filter $line ; done
A,3300
B,844
C,304
C,404
M,55
```

Preprocessing the data with `datamash` and gets me sorted data i can feed to `my_filter` line by line:

```bash
$ sort -u testfile | datamash -t, -g1 collapse 2 
A,3300
B,8440,8443,8444
C,304,404
M,5502,5511
```

Now here is `my_filter`:

```bash
$ cat my_filter
#!/bin/bash
_longest_match () {
  if ((${#1}>${#2})); then
    long="$1" short="$2"
  else
    long="$2" short="$1"
  fi

  lshort=${#short}
  score=0
  for ((l=score+1;l<=lshort;++l)); do
    sub="${short:0:l}"

    [[ $long != $sub* ]] && break
    subfound="$sub" score="$l"
  done

  if ((score)); then
    printf '%s\n' "$subfound"
  fi
} # ----------  end of function _longest_match  ----------


_output () {
  for item in $(echo "$@"|tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u) ; do
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$key" "$item"
  done
} # ----------  end of function _output  ----------

declare -A matches
declare -A no_matches

key=$1
shift

for item in $( printf '%s\n' "$@"| sort -nr ); do
  if [ -z "$one" ]; then
    one=$1
    two=${2:-$1}
    shift 2
  else
    two=$1
    shift
  fi

  three=$(_longest_match $one $two)

  [ ${#three} -gt 0 ] && matches[$key]+="$three " || no_matches[$key]+="$one $two "
  [ ${#three} -gt 0 ] && one="$three" || one="$two"
done

  _output "${matches[@]} ${no_matches[@]}" | sort -u
```

Found some inspiration for the `_longest_match` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23297950

I did some additional testing with double entries in the testfile:

```bash
$ cat testfile.new 
A,3300
B,8440
B,8440
U,3
U,7
U,7
U,73
B,8440
B,8443
B,8444
B,976
C,304
C,404
M,5502
M,5511
```

And the result was:

```bash
$ sort -u testfile | datamash -t, -g1 collapse 2  \
| tr ',' ' ' | while read line ; do ./my_filter $line ; done
A,3300
B,844
B,976
C,304
C,404
M,55
U,3
U,7
```

Does that look like your expected result?

Comment: Yes, at first glance it definitely does. It looks perfect to me. Let me try your code here and give you feedback later on. Thanks @markgraf

Comment: Just noticed this is faster if testfile gets sorted an uniq-ed first. Updating script...

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```c
BEGIN { OFS=FS="," }

prefixlength[$1] == "" {
        # First time seeing this label.
        # Remember the full string and its length.

        prefix[$1] = $2
        prefixlength[$1] = length($2)
        next
}

{
        # Compare the current string to the (current) longest
        # prefix related to this label. Update the prefix length
        # to the longest common prefix length.

        for (i = 1; i <= prefixlength[$1]; ++i)
                if (substr(prefix[$1],i,1) != substr($2,i,1)) {
                        prefixlength[$1] = i-1
                        break
                }
}

END {
        # Output labels and their longest prefix.

        for (i in prefix)
                print i, substr(prefix[i],1,prefixlength[i])
}
```

For the given input, this would do the following:

```bash
$ awk -f script file
A,3300
B,844
C,
M,55
```

Since this shows an empty prefix when the computed longest prefix length is zero, you may want to modify the code somewhat if you need to show all strings in this special case:

```c
BEGIN { OFS=FS="," }

prefixlength[$1] == "" {
        # First time seeing this label.
        # Remember the full string and its length.

        prefix[$1] = $2
        prefixlength[$1] = length($2)
        next
}

{
        # Remember all found strings in a sort of "array". The
        # strings added after the first will only ever be used
        # if the prefix length ends up as zero.

        prefix[$1] = prefix[$1] SUBSEP $2
}

{
        # Compare the current string to the (current) longest
        # prefix related to this label. Update the prefix length
        # to the longest common prefix length.

        for (i = 1; i <= prefixlength[$1]; ++i)
                if (substr(prefix[$1],i,1) != substr($2,i,1)) {
                        prefixlength[$1] = i-1
                        break
                }
}

END {
        # Output labels and their longest prefix. If the prefix length
        # is zero for a label, output all collected strings as separate
        # lines.

        for (i in prefix)
                if (prefixlength[i] > 0)
                        print i, substr(prefix[i],1,prefixlength[i])
                else {
                        n = split(prefix[i],a,SUBSEP)
                        for (j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
                                print i, a[j]
                }
}
```

Testing:

```bash
$ awk -f script file
A,3300
B,844
C,304
C,404
M,55
```